# WAMP phpmyadmin error code 500 When click on any table to view data

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am getting Error code 500 ( Error in processing request, Internal server error ) when I click on any database table after login to phpmyadmin. Screenshot attached.

Any help ? How can I fix this issue ?

[image]

Comment: What is in the server logs? Apache error log and `/var/log/user.log` for instance?

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: Server version: 5.5.38

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting the same error. I am using Mysql 5.6. When I googled for the same, I found that this error may be due to exhaust in memory.

Reference Url: https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/01/24/mysql-server-memory-usage-2/